# How to capture a specific value located between the h2 nodes of an HTML page?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I an using the `rvest` package in `R` to capture a specific text located on a webpage.
The text I am interested to capture is "Hotel ABC - An All-Inclusive Resort".

Its location within the `html` codes of the webpage is shown below:

```
<h2 class="hp__hotel-name" id="hp_hotel_name">
<span class="hp__hotel-type-badge">Hotel</span>
Hotel ABC - An All-Inclusive Resort
</h2>
```

How can I use rvest to capture that specific text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the following sibling of the span, anchored by the parent h2 id.

```
library(rvest)

html <- '<h2 class="hp__hotel-name" id="hp_hotel_name">
<span class="hp__hotel-type-badge">Hotel</span>
Hotel ABC - An All-Inclusive Resort
</h2>'

read_html(html) %>%
  html_node(xpath = "//*[@id='hp_hotel_name']/span/following-sibling::text()[1]") %>%
  html_text(trim = T)
```

Comment: It is extracting the word "Hotel" instead of "Hotel ABC - An All-Inclusive Resort"

Comment: Oops my bad. Updated.